# How to calculate size of svg feGaussianBlur

Tags: svg, blur, dropshadow

I'm trying to programatically determine the size of filter for applying drop shadow effect using feGaussianBlur. I've been searching a lot about it but couldn't find a proper way to do it. Is there a way to calculate the same. given blur, dx and dy values?

```
<filter id="drop shadow">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="x" result="result"/>
  <feOffset in="result" dx="dx" dy="dy" result="shadow"/>
  <feMerge>
     <feMergeNode in="shadow"/>
     <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </feMerge>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely exact, but assuming a viewBox that matches the dimensions of the shape -> for smaller values of stdDeviation (<15ish), the blur will be at 5% opacity (about where its hard to see) at around 85% of the stdDeviation value in pixels - rounded up. In other words - a stdDeviation blur of 10 will add about 9 pixels of blur around the original shape.

To calculate the appropriate filter region, you need to getBBox() for the shape to find its width and height. Add the appropriate stdDeviation padding to both. Add the absolute value of dx and dy to width & height respectively. Express that as a % of the shape's original height and width. Subtract 1 from each value. And now you have your -x% and -y% for the filter region. And your filter region width and height will be 100% + x% and 100% + y%.